# Generate a random number that is between 0 and x but no more than 10

Tags: javascript, protractor

currently I use the following to generate a random number;

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (listItems.length - 0))
```

The problem with that is that `listItems.length` could be anywhere between 3 or 20,000 and I only need a low number, preferably no more than 10, but it also needs to be less than or equal to `listItems.length`, so obviously I cant just generate a number between 0 and 10 because i could get 7 but the list length may only be 5 which will cause me problems later on.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: `Math.min(listItems.length, 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rand = Math.random() * Math.min(listItems.length, 10) | 0;
```